# Concrete 5 Sitemap generator stalls out with an error?

Tags: sitemap, concrete5

When trying to generate a sitemap I keep getting this error and the job stalls out
I noticed this error in 8.4.3 so i updated to 8.4.4 and it still is present

Error:

> Argument 2 passed to
>   Concrete\Core\Page\Sitemap\Element\SitemapPage::__construct() must
>   implement interface Concrete\Core\Url\UrlInterface, instance of
>   League\Url\Url given, called in
>   /home2/cedarcom/public_html/updates/concrete5-8.4.4_remote_updater/concrete/src/Page/Sitemap/SitemapGenerator.php
>   on line 316

If anyone has some insight on how this, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/pull/7363, so the upcoming concrete5 8.5.0 won't suffer this problem.

If you want to fix your running installation, you can edit these two files:

- `/home2/cedarcom/public_html/updates/concrete5-8.4.4_remote_updater/concrete/src/Page/Sitemap/Element/SitemapPage.php`
- `/home2/cedarcom/public_html/updates/concrete5-8.4.4_remote_updater/concrete/src/Page/Sitemap/Element/SitemapPageAlternativeLanguage.php`

by replacing this line

```
 use Concrete\Core\Url\UrlInterface;
```

with

```
use League\Url\UrlInterface;
```

Comment: Thanks So much! This fixed the problem